# Blank output on db query

Tags: python, django, iterator

im trying to run this python-django code below, but am getting *a blank output*

```
SitePaths = PathsOfDomain.objects.filter(pathToScan__contains="www.myapp.com")

        return SitePaths
```

`PathsOfDomain` is the object representation of a db table.

I'm trying to iterate through a db field name `pathToScan` and output each value

If someone can please shed some light on this.

Thank you.

Comment: In the Django ORM, `Model` instances model *one row* in the database. It looks like you created an instance, you did not query the table. Did you mean to list items related to `Tld` instead?

Comment: Martjn - Im trying to select all the db fields with FKtoTld_id=domain_in_session and output the value of pathToScan column

Comment: Looks like `SitePaths` is an object, and not a queryset. You can always do `for key, value in SitePaths.__dict__:`

Comment: @karthikr - Please post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant to query for matching `PathsOfDomain` rows in the database, use the `.objects` attribute to create a query set:

```
SitePaths = PathsOfDomain.objects.filter(FKtoTld__id=domain_in_session)
```

See [Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/) in the Django documentation.

Alternatively, if there is a foreign key relationship between the `Tld` and `PathsOfDomain` objects, use [the related objects manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) instead:

```
SitePaths = domain_in_session.pathsofdomain_set.all()
```

Comment: Please see updated code. This code isn't working, but if i manually run the sql at the db end of: SELECT * FROM mydb
WHERE `pathToScan` LIKE '%www.myapp.com%';    it shows 58 records..